# Vertical and Horizontal Mirroring in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have an html table, say 50x50. I need to come up with an algorithm to mirror vertically and horizontally. I'm using javascript/jquery to replace images in the table. Vertical and horizontal mirroring must be separated from each other so they can be activated/deactivated independently. I'm new to programming and stack overflow so if I'm not sure what I need to provide/describe. Hope this question makes sense.

Here is my table currently.

```
<table>
  <% 50.times do %>
    <tr>
      <% 50.times do %>
        <td><img src='/assets/floor_tile.png'></td>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

So for example. If I click on the top left cell, and horizontal mirroring is on, then the top right cell will change as well.

My current js, not sure if this helps as it was more of a test at the time.

```
  // Get mouse status.
  var down = false;
  $(document).mousedown(function() {
    down = true;
  }).mouseup(function() {
    down = false;  
  });

  // Basic tile change test.
  $("img").mouseover(function(){
    var tile_to_change = this;
    if(down) {
      $(tile_to_change).attr('src', '/assets/wall_tile.png');
    } 
    else {   
    }
  });

  $("img").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', '/assets/wall_tile.png');
  })
```

Comment: You need to add some code that shows what you're trying to mirror (like the click handler for instance). Then we can show you how to change what you have to do what you want.

Comment: If you're mirroring horizontally _and_ vertically, if you click on the upper left corner, shouldn't it activate the lower right corner?

Comment: If both are on it would activate the top right and bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing what you want is the following. I'll assume you have variables `horizontalMirror` and `verticalMirror` setup somewhere else (by a checkbox handler for instance):

```
// Get mouse status.
var down = false;
$(document).mousedown(function() {
  down = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
  down = false;  
});

function make_wall_tile(selector, noVertMirror) {
    selector.attr('src', '/assets/wall_tile.png');
    td = selector.parent();
    tr = td.parent();
    column = td.index("td");
    if(horizontalMirror) {
        hmirror_td = tr.children("td").get(-1-column);
        hmirror_td.attr('src', '/assets/wall_tile.png');
    }
    if(verticalMirror && !noVertMirror) {
        table = tr.parent();
        row = tr.index("tr");
        vmirrorTr = table.children("tr").get(-1-row);
        td = vmirrorTr.children("td").get(column);
        img = td.children("img");
        make_wall_tile(img, true);
    }
}

// Basic tile change test.
$("img").mouseover(function(){
  var tile_to_change = this;
  if(down) {
    $(tile_to_change).attr('src', '/assets/wall_tile.png');
  } 
  else {   
  }
});

$("img").mousedown(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', '/assets/wall_tile.png');
})
```

I may be a little fuzzy on the number of .parent()/.children() needed because I think some browsers (or maybe it's the standard) add tbody/trow/w/e elements in the table, but this should give you the basic idea.